# Run function inside of another function, but only after ajax has finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a function that is run inside of another function, but sometimes it seems my ajax call to the server isn't finished running before it calls the function.

```
    function getPlans(row, user, id, type) {
      $.get( "/plans/" + user + "/" + id + "/" + type + "", function(data) {
        $("#permissions_" + row + "_plan_type").empty();
        $(data).each(function(i, e) {
          $("#permissions_" + row + "_plan_type").append("<option>" + e + "</option>");
        })
      }).done(function() {
        getPermissions(row, user, type);
      })
    }
```

Comment: hmmm, i think you might be getting the callback's mixed up. your `function(data)` callback gets called first, then your `done` callback. Why do you have them in two different callback's? To run `getPermissions` after the `.each()` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a **quick solution** you can make an `.ajax` call with `async: false`

```
 function getPlans(row, user, id, type) {
  $.ajax({
    url:"/plans/" + user + "/" + id + "/" + type + "",
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(data) {
        $("#permissions_" + row + "_plan_type").empty();
        $(data).each(function(i, e) {
          $("#permissions_" + row + "_plan_type").append("<option>" + e + "</option>");
        })
      },
      async:false // make synchronous
  });

  getPermissions(row, user, type);
}
```

**Solution 2:** You can use [`.when`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) from jQuery.

```
function getPlans(row, user, id, type) {
    var dfd = $.Deferred();
    $.when( $.get( "/plans/" + user + "/" + id + "/" + type + ""))
        .done(function(data) {
            $("#permissions_" + row + "_plan_type").empty();
            $(data).each(function(i, e) {
              $("#permissions_" + row + "_plan_type").append("<option>" + e + "</option>");
            })
        });

    getPermissions(row, user, type);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try calling `getPermissions()` from success callback.

```
function getPlans(row, user, id, type) {
    $.get( "/plans/" + user + "/" + id + "/" + type + "", function(data) {
        $("#permissions_" + row + "_plan_type").empty();
        $(data).each(function(i, e) {
          $("#permissions_" + row + "_plan_type").append("<option>" + e + "</option>");
        });
        getPermissions(row, user, type);
    });
 }
```